# Using luigi.LocalTarget with PdfPages in python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, luigi

The below code snippet worked fine for python2, but does not work for python3. This code snippet is intended to allow for a luigi workflow to write to a multipage PDF, while still using the LocalTarget context manager that allows for atomicity.

```
import luigi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = luigi.LocalTarget('test.pdf')
with test.open('wb') as fh, PdfPages(fh) as outf:
    plt = plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

This works in python2, but in python3 leads to the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ba62e5b716d2> in <module>
----> 1 with test.open('wb') as fh, PdfPages(fh) as outf:
      2     plt = plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

~/miniconda3/envs/cat3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py in __init__(self, filename, keep_empty, metadata)
   2386 
   2387         """
-> 2388         self._file = PdfFile(filename, metadata=metadata)
   2389         self.keep_empty = keep_empty
   2390 

~/miniconda3/envs/cat3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py in __init__(self, filename, metadata)
    445         self.fh = fh
    446         self.currentstream = None  # stream object to write to, if any
--> 447         fh.write(b"%PDF-1.4\n")    # 1.4 is the first version to have alpha
    448         # Output some eight-bit chars as a comment so various utilities
    449         # recognize the file as binary by looking at the first few

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

How can I retain this atomic functionality in python3?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I found this line in the Luigi repository in the definition of LocalTarget:

```
def open(self, mode='r'):
    rwmode = mode.replace('b', '').replace('t', '')
    ...
```

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/local_target.py#L159

It seems that they are not doing byte writing whatsoever (at least in the current version). I would definitely bring this up with them in the Github Issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in the working of LocalTarget, so i do not know if there is a reason for the removal of the b-flag, or if this is a bug.

A way to work around this is to wrap the code using the `temporary_path` function:

```
import luigi

class BinaryFileExample(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("simple_binary_file.extension")

    def run(self):
        with self.output().temporary_path() as my_binary_file_path:
            with open(my_binary_file_path, 'wb') as inner_file:
                newFileBytes = [123, 3, 255, 0, 100]
                for byte in newFileBytes:
                    inner_file.write(byte.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
```